# Error en funcion edit Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hola que tal soy nuevo en el area de desarrollo, tengo una dudua con esta funcion ma error al ejecutarla

```php
public function editBrand(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $brand = Brand::find($id);
        $brand->name = $request->name;
        $brand->save();
        return redirect('admin/marcas')->with('mensaje', "El artículo $brand->id fue actualizado exitosamente.");
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y la variable id si llega con un valor o llega vacía?

Comment: Tendria que llegar con un valor, esta es mi otro funcion showedit ```public function showBrandEdit($id)
    {
        $brands = Brand::find();
        return view('admin/brandsEdit', [
            'brands' => $brands,
        ]);
    }```

Comment: Pasaje un id de los que sabes tienes en tu bd, por ejemplo pásame el valor 1 y dime qué te devuelve

Comment: Ya lo resolví, gracias al dato que me sugeriste sobre el id en esta funcion no le estaba dando como parametro el $id ```$brand = Brand::find(); ```` ahora quedo asi ``` public function showBrandEdit($id)
    {
        $brand = Brand::find($id);
        return view('admin/brandEdit', [
            'brand' => $brand,

        ]);
    } ``` Muchas gracias.